# Assigning even number of FK's in a table based on an even number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, count

I have two tables where I have a situation like this:

```
 Table1
column1
column2
column3
column4
column5
```

Table 2 structure:

```
 Table2
 Col1
 Col2
 Col3
 Table1FK
```

My table 1 currently has 3 records inside it, and the table 2 shall contain more records than table 1 (one to many relationship between these two). I want to assign an even number of records from Table 2 to table 1 FK's.

For example:

If table 2 has 20 records and if table 1 has 3 records

I will divide these two and get an even number, 6.66 in this case.

So the table1 PK's should be assigned like

6-6-8

or

7 7 6 (this one is more even)

And then table 1 PK under identity let's say 1500 would have 7 of it's corresponding FK's in table 2 , 7 for Identity 1501 , and 6 for identity 1502

Starting point is that I should divide these:

```
var evenAmountOfFKs = table2.Count()/table1.Count();
```

What would be the next step here, and how could I achieve this ?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you are trying to do here. This doesn't make any sense to me at all. The only thing I can remotely come up with is perhaps you are generating test data and trying to automate setting foreign key values??

Comment: @SeanLange yes exactly... Each foreign key should have assigned that many values how many the table2.Count()/table1.count() has... The resulting number of those two numbers divided should be how many each FK would have corresponding values in table2 ...

Comment: Exactly what? Generating dummy data? If that is the case, just use ROW_NUMBER. If you want real help you are going to have to provide some table definitions and sample data along with the desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

No matter how weird the requirement seems, the math was fun.

At first, we have to determine the number of parents:

```
DECLARE @NoParents int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1);
```

Both parents and children can be numbered starting with `0`, and then a child can be assigned to parent x with `x = ChildNo % @NoParents`:

```
DECLARE @NoParents int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1);

WITH
  Parents AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1)-1 AS ParentNo
    FROM Table1
  ),
  Children AS (
    SELECT Col1, Col1, Col1,
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1)-1) % @NoParents AS ParentNo
    FROM Table2
  )
SELECT p.column1, p.column2, p.column3, p.column4, p.column5, c.Col1, c.Col1
FROM Parents p
  INNER JOIN Children c ON p.ParentNo = c.ParentNo;
```

This will produce an "even" assignment.